# Getting user data through Facebook Graph API in Swift 3

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, swift3, facebook-login

Hi to my fellow developers 
Just a simple question. How can I get the data of user through Facebook Graph API after login in app?
There's a sample in Facebook Documentation, but its not working.

Comment: Again just go through the Doc you will get idea about permission what you want to get.

Comment: Add code and errors.

Comment: I used Facebook sample but it didn't return a response

Comment: we dont know what sample you used and what error you got, add some code.

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: here
 [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/graph)

Answer (score 0):

```
let permisions = ["public_profile" ,"email" ,"user_birthday"]
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permisions, fromViewController: vc) { (result, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
    if result.isCancelled {
          //do error handling for canceled 
    } else {
    let fbLoginResult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
    let facebookToken = fbLoginResult.token.tokenString
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil){
    // handle error 
    }
    let email =  result.valueForKey("email") as? String ?? ""
    let firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? String ?? ""
    let lastName = result.valueForKey("last_name") as? String ?? ""
    // do stuffs with email or first name or last name

    })
```

this is swift version 2.3 but with little modification it will convert to swift 3